# Static function for multiple files

Tags: c, bare-metal, static-functions

Language : C
Environment : bare-metal

This program have many sub-modules. I hope in the functions of each sub-module can't not be visible/used by other sub-modules except that the functions are the API functions. 
If the sub-modules only contains single file, the simplest way is using static function except the API functions. However, how is that work for multi-functions sub-modules?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can have multiple `static` functions in each linkable object module, the answer is *yes*. If that is not the root of your question, you may want to consider rewording it to better drive the *problem* you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If talking C a module is a translation unit is a file.  Concluding from this backward there are no modules consisting of more then one file in C.

So to answer your question: You **cannot** have a static function being made accessable by more then one file.